# JQuery - get element through id and then through class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like this

```
<div id="div1">
   <span class="label">some text</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
   <span class="label">some text</span>
</div>
```

I want to select a given span through id and then throu class. Something like `#div1.label` or `#div2.span` but this way doesn't work. How I can?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a space to indicate the element is a child:

```
$('#div1 .label');
$('#div2 span');
$('#div2 span.label');
```

`#div1.label` would select an element with id div1 and a class of label.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
$("#div1 span.label")
```

if you use `#div1.label` you're actually selecting an element with id `div1` AND having the class `label`.

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it:

```
$("#div1 .label");
```

**[Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)**

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

---

You could also make it more specific:

```
$("#div1 > .label");
```

**[Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**

> Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$('#div1 .label')` and `$('#div2 span')`. You need separate using space

Answer (score 1):

*#div1.label or #div2.span*

You are thinking of it wrong, in your selectors you are grabbing, ID of **div1** with a *class* of div1.**label**. (Which is not the way your HTML is structured, and what you are looking for)

You need these to be:

```
$('#div1 .label');
$('#div2 .label');
```

The space inbetween is just as in CSS syntax in that it looks for a child element, which in this case needs a class of *label* (you could also put in **span.label** for even more specificity)

If you want it to be more vague and capture all the divs with a span.label inside of them you could do:

```
$('div span.label'); // this would capture all of them
$('div[id^="div"] span.label'); // assuming they all start with the ID "div" then a #
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code worked for me `$('#prettyId > label');`